# Logstash convert entry // JSON

Tags: javascript, json, http, logstash

when I send a http Post to logstach my entry seems sth like that:

```
{
  "_index": "logstash-2014.11.25",
  "_type": "logs",
  "_id": "PyALYOSjRi-N8cfg8axyMg",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "message": "technology=apache",
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2014-11-25T11:57:56.931Z",
    "host": "127.0.0.1"
  },
  "sort": [
    1416916676931,
    1416916676931
  ]
}
```

Are you have any idea to handle the message so that it seems like thsi:

```
{
  "_index": "logstash-2014.11.25",
  "_type": "logs",
  "_id": "PyALYOSjRi-N8cfg8axyMg",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {

    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2014-11-25T11:57:56.931Z",
    "host": "127.0.0.1"
  },
  "sort": [
    1416916676931,
    1416916676931
  ]
**"technology": "apache"**
}
```

Comment: You can use  mutate filter to override enttry in JSON

Comment: You want to extract a `key=value` pair from the message field into a separate field? The [kv filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/kv) should be helpful.